# MySQL Computation as rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider a table in MySQL Database

```
 id  |  A  |  B  |  C

 1   |  10 | 20  |  30
 2   |  13 | 32  |  44
 3   |  34 | 24  |  92
```

How do I compute generate something like

```
compute    |  A  |  B  |  C

sum        | 57  |  76 | 166
average    |
```

**Usually**

```
sum(A) as total
```

gives a column but I need it to be a row

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a union of two queries, one which finds the sums, the other which finds the averages:

```
SELECT 'sum' AS compute, SUM(A) AS A, SUM(B) AS B, SUM(C) AS C FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'average', AVG(A), AVG(B), AVG(C) FROM yourTable
```

[image]

### Demo